# Having to change a lot of code when changing sessions - php, html

Tags: php, html, session

So basically my code works fine, i'm just finding myself writing a lot of code which could possibly be solved by a function, javascript/jquery or something else which im not sure of. (And i'm sure this is already a problem solved (so sorry for asking it again, i just couldnt find the answer anywhere :( )).

Pretty much the problem is, i have to change the content of my website when the user is logged in and logged out (using sessions). For example, this is my navigation and i have use the php if statements inside of the html to display different list items depending on if the user is logged in or out. This is my code so far:

```
<header>
<a href="home.php">
    <h1>My website</h1>
    <h2>Stackoverflow is awesome!<h2>
</a>
<nav>

    <ul>
        <?php if($_SESSION['current_user'] == "") : ?> <!-- dont really want these if statements in my code -->
            <a href="home.php" class="selected"><li>Home</li></a>
            <a href="sign-up.php"><li>Sign-up / Log in</li></a>
        <?php else : ?>
            <a href="home.php"><li><?php  echo "Hello:\t" . $_SESSION['current_user'] . "!"; ?></li></a>
            <a href="logout_engine.php"><li><?php echo "log out";  ?></li></a>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </ul>
</nav>
</header>
```

Is there anyway easy way to use sessions to change what the content looks like? Eg:

```
if($_SESSION['current_user'] == "")
{
//header('Location: home.php');
}
else
{
//header('Location: logged_in_home.php');
}
/* However this would require making a whole new .php file
 * which seems a bit over the top for just subtle changes.
 * I just dont want to have this in-built php if statements everywhere in my html
 (this is just one solution i thought of)
 */
```

Sorry if this was a stupid/repeated question (im pretty new to php), just not sure where to go from here. A link to a tutorial or a answer on how web developers go around solving this would be great Thanks in advance! :D

**ALSO (Edited)**

if the website has different access levels such as: admins and public users. I would have to make more new pages. Example:

```
if($_SESSION['current_user'] == "")
{
    header('Location: home.php');
}
else
{
    if($_SESSION['current_access_level'] = "admin")
    {
    header('Location: admin_home.php');
    }
    else
    {
    header('Location: logged_in_home.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: did you use `session_start();` at the top of the page?

Comment: @MohsenShakibafar yeah lol, assume everything is set up properly :)